# How do I insert an array at an array specific index without removing existing data at specified index using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a array, in that array I want to add another array on a particular index if the condition is met.

This is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('rulesApp');
app.controller('myController2', ['$scope', '$rootScope'] {
      $scope.rows = function() {
        $rootScope.rows.push({
          id: $rootScope.input_columns.length,
          name: 'Name'
          dropped: false,
          dataType: '',
          type: 'input',
          path: ''
        }); //Json in which I need to add array
        //some code
        for (var i = 0; i < cellValues.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < $rootScope.input_columns.length; j++) {
            $rootScope.rows.splice(j, 0, cellValues); //I want to add
            cellValues array to rows Json on specified index
          }
        }
      });
```

Attaching image for initial object

[image]

After splice:

[image]

Here I have a array of two elements, I want to add another array on a specified index with existing data too. for that I tried many solution then tried splice with `splice` it is removing existing index and adding new index. But I want that on the specified index I can add the array without overriding previous data. I tried using `$rootScope.rows[i].push(cellValues)` but it is giving `error: function not defined`.

How can I insert array data in JSON without overriding the existing data. I have attached two screenshots for better understanding of the issue I am facing

Is there any way that at specified index I can insert the `cellValue` array with existing data

This is the structure being created after trying slice code. Now cell value array is created on 1-3 index then on 4th & 5th index previous data is coming. But I want to add `cellValues` data to specified index itself with existing data.

[image]

Comment: But in this it is replacing or adding new data on particular index. I want to add new data with existing data on that index. How can I achieve that

Comment: What are the nested `for` loops doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I see various problems with your code.

**Splice**

Basically what you are doing here is adding an array of strings into an array of objects.

```
$rootScope.rows=[{...}, {...}];
cellValues=["some", "value"];

$rootScope.rows.splice(j, 0, cellValues);

console.log($rootScope.rows) //[{...}, {...}, ["some", "value"]]
```

**Splice**

```
rowValues=$rootScope.rows.slice(0,j).concat(cellValues, rowValues);
```

Here you are removing all array item up til index `j`. And then merging these with the cellValues, which, like the example above will return a mixed array of array of strings and objects:

```
[["some", "value"], {...}, {...}]
```

#### Solution

If I understand you correct you want to merge(concatinate) to arrays. This can be done like below:

**Array merge**

```
$rootScope.rows=$rootScope.rows.concat(cellValues);
```

Example

```
var rows=[1,2,3];

var cellValues=[4,5,6];

var newRow=rows.concat(cellValues);

console.log(newRow); //[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**Object merge**

If you need to merge two objects (Associative arrays) you're able to use `angular.extend(obj1, obj2)`

Example

```
var obj1={
  one:1,
  two:2,
  three:3
}

var obj2={
  four:4,
  five:5,
  six:6
}

var obj3=angular.extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj3);
/*
  {
    one:1,
    two:2,
    three:3,
    four:4,
    five:5,
    six:6
  }
*/
```

[Jsbin example here](http://jsbin.com/nunicucivi/edit?js,console)

#### UPDATE

Since you have a given index (`j`), you will have to use that to identify a certain nested array on the rows array. Then you're going to merge the identified nested array with the new array (cellValues);

Example

```
//nested arrays
var rows=[
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,14,15,16],
];

//index of the nested array to merge
var arrayIndex=1;

//new array to merge with nested array (rows[arrayIndex])
var valuesToAdd=[22,33,44];

//Reference the nested array and merge it with the new array.
rows[arrayIndex]=rows[arrayIndex].concat(valuesToAdd);

console.log(rows[arrayIndex]); //[5, 6, 7, 8, 22, 33, 44]
```

[Jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/qikilenodi/edit?js,console)

However, in your case you want to add the values from the cellvalues string array to an identified object in the rows array. This can be done in two ways: 1) adding a paths property to the identified object, or 2) add each string as a property to the identified object.

**Option 1:**

```
for (var j = 0; j < $rootScope.input_columns.length; j++) {
    rows[j].paths=cellValues;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
for (var j = 0; j < $rootScope.input_columns.length; j++) {
    for(var i=0;i<cellValues.length; i++) {
        rows[j]["path"+i]=cellValues[i];
    }
}
```

[Jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/cavuseloxi/edit?js,console)

Comment: But i want to merge the two arrays at particular index only..like in the second loop j specifies the index. So on that index I want to add cellValues with existing values

Comment: I tried this solution but it was giving $rootScope.rows[j].concat is not a function error

Comment: So basically what you are trying to do is actually to merge an object with an array of strings, since cellrows seems to be an array of strings and rows is an array containing objects. Its difficult to understand what you actually want to achieve? Why cant to cellvalues array just be a property of the object? You could also add each value as a property of the object(path1, path2, ...pathN)(Not recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

array in angular are behaved same. they have same prototype methods such as slice, splice. just set your array to a, b, d in the example and it will work for you.

```js
a = [1, 2, 5], 
  b = [3, 4], 
  indexWhereToInsert = 2, //postion where you want to insert (index +1 ) actually 
  d = [];

d = a.slice(indexWhereToInsert, a.length)
alert(a.slice(0, indexWhereToInsert).concat(b, d))
```

Comment: I tried your solution but with this it is inserting b on 0 index and the values at zero index comes to first index. In my case b contains array so suppose it has 4 element so from 0-3 index array value is coming and on 4th index the previous 0th index value is coming. I want to insert the new array on that index only with existing data

Comment: can you show how you used this code? and is it happening in my given example?

Comment: for(var i=0;i<cellValues.length;i++){
     for(var j=0;j<$rootScope.input_columns.length;j++){
      rowValues =$rootScope.rows.slice(j, $rootScope.rows.length)
                        rowValues=$rootScope.rows.slice(0, j).concat(cellValues,rowValues);
     }

Comment: $rootScope.rows contains an array of two element as shown in first screenshot. cellValues contain 4 elements which is shown in second screeshot 0th index

Comment: I have attached a new screenshot on my post for better understanding. this structure is being created after trying your suggested code. Can you please suggest how can I merge existing data with the new array data on any specified index.

Comment: you are using it wrong way... can you please create a plunker reflecting your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I created an array inside $rootScope.rows Json like:

```
$scope.rows = function() {
        $rootScope.rows.push({
          id: $rootScope.input_columns.length,
          name: 'Name'
          dropped: false,
          dataType: '',
          type: 'input',
          path: '',
          rowValue:[]
        }); //Json in which I need to add array
        //some code
        for (var i = 0; i < cellValues.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < $rootScope.input_columns.length; j++) {
            $rootScope.rows[j].rowValue.push(cellValues); //I am able to get array inside an array at specified index

          }
        }
      });
```